# Pushing figures into holes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ - smooth curve, $\gamma_i(0)=\gamma_i(1)$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the areas bounded by the corresponding curves. . Suppose we have an $X_1 $-shaped hole, and into this hole we want to push as large an area of ​​a rigid $X_2$-shape form. How to calculate the largest such area for two given $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$? More precisely, to what problem with a known solution can I reduce this problem?

Comment: I don’t think this has a general solution

Comment: Oh, this is expected. Therefore, I would like to see some work on topics related to this task.

Comment: “What is work related to this?” is not a good question for this site, but you can browse relevant tags (like convex-geometry) and questions (like https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342037/to-find-the-largest-regular-n-gon-contained-in-a-given-convex-region)